# Test a C++ object validity as though it was a pointer

Tags: c++, object, null, operator-overloading, operators

Let's say I have an object which may not be properly initialized, but it's not simply a null pointer to object; it's an object with empty or uninitialized members. But I want to check it in as readable a manner as if it was a pointer:

```
if (Object) use(Object);
```

For example, Object may have an `int` field which, if 0, is considered uninitialized. Then, I can make an overload of the ! operator like this:

```
bool operator!() const {return intField == 0;}
```

I can use it like so:

```
if (! Object)  initialize (Object);
```

The thing is, if I want to test for the opposite condition (non-null-ness), I can't do just this:

```
if (Object)...
```

I only find awkward possibilities:

```
if (! (! Object))...  // awful
if (Object.notNull()) // not so bad
```

The one closest to my wishes is confusing:

```
bool operator()() {return intField != 0;}
if (Object())...   // it looks a lot like an argument-less constructor
```

AFAIK, there is no bool-returning empty operator (something like `bool operator() {...}`) or any other trick or idiom that can achieve this.

Any ideas of a readable solution other than the `notNull()` method? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide a type conversion operator, to allow conversion to `bool`:

```
explicit operator bool() const {return intField != 0;}
```

This allows it to be used in boolean contexts, such as `if` conditions. `explicit` is optional, but a good idea to prevent potentially confusing conversions to numeric types.

An alternative approach is to use [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) or similar, to make any type nullable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to be careful by using operator overloading to indicate validity or an initialized state--especially if you will ever hold a pointer or reference to an object of this type.

For this case, I would recommend the following explicit notation:

```
if (Object.isValid()) use(Object);
```

This way, it's obvious to the next person who reads your code exactly what you're doing here.  Operator overloading should always be obvious to the person using it, and a true/false check on an object means it *exists* or not, not necessarily if it's *valid* or not.

Comment: I half-agree, because code should be as clear as possible. But, on the other hand, overloading operators is a lot about treating objects conceptually, and if you are used to writing (or at least, reading) `if (pointer)` to test that `pointer` is not null, you might find that `if (object)` is conceptually clear. It's a matter of finding a good balance between clarity, verbosity and conceptual adequacy.